Automating SQL Queries for Data Views in Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Handle Journey and Email Version Changes
I'm currently using SQL queries on Salesforce Marketing Cloud Data Views to generate reports based on emails sent via Journey Builder. Here is an example of the query I'm using:
SELECT j.JobId,
       j.Category,
       j.AccountUserID,
       j.PickupTime
FROM _job j
JOIN _JourneyActivity ja
ON j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectId = ja.JourneyActivityObjectId
WHERE ja.ActivityId = '123'
AND j.Category LIKE 'version%'
AND j.PickupTime IS NOT NULL

The issue I’m facing is that whenever a new version of a journey is created or the email content is updated, a new ActivityId is generated, which forces me to manually update all the SQL queries to reflect these changes. This is time-consuming and prone to errors.
Is there a way to automate or dynamically handle these version changes in SQL queries so that I don’t have to update them manually every time a new version is published or an email is updated?
